# How to deserialize a vector<char> with Yaml-Cpp?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I am using Yaml-Cpp to generate the input string to begin with. It seems I am somehow generating an incorrect serialization of the vector, though, because when I try to access that member from a loaded Yaml Node, I get "TypedBadConversion".

Entirely besides helping understand how to generate the Yaml to begin with (which I am interested in as well!) does anyone see why the string in question is invalid? Here is a test program and its output:

**Test Program**

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
using namespace YAML;
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
std::string         Command( "- ./rsc/cudaExample0.sh\n- 10.62.4.214/16\n- 2.0.19.136\n- 5000\n- 5000\n- 0\n-\n  - b\n  - i\n  - n\n  - \" \"\n  - \"-\"\n  - t\n  - \" \"\n- 72" );
YAML::Node          Test = Load( Command );
std::vector<char>   Payload;
    Payload = Test[6].as<std::vector<char> >();
    std::cout << Payload[1] << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Starting /noname/src/testyaml/TestYaml...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::TypedBadConversion<char>'
  what():  yaml-cpp: error at line 0, column 0: bad conversion
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/noname/src/testyaml/TestYaml exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in yaml-cpp; I opened a [issue](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=224) on the project page, and it is fixed at the repository's tip.

Comment: OMG I stepped through that line without batting an eye. I need to make sure this fixes my issue, then I will be right back.

Comment: That solved my problem. Wow. You are really dedicated. Thanks for looking into this. And thanks for yaml-cpp. You're the main[only?] dev, right? I'm trying to use it in my final project at uni, so I'm glad for it!

Comment: Yep, I'm the only dev. Thanks!